# Finding floor and ceil of every element after inserted into array efficiently

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, sortedlist

Assume array has elements `[1,n]`. There is an continuous input of elements (m queries) one by one. Like below.

1. 5 so you have to print 1 as floor and 10 as ceil then array becomes `[1,5,10]`
2. 2 so print 1 as floor and 5 as ceil and array becomes `[1,2,5,10]`

like this m queries are given. Floor and ceil and can be found with O(log n) time complexity as we are maintaining arraylist sorted.

But the problem is finding element position for insertion is `O(log n)` and inserting is `O(n)` for moving other numbers in worst case which results in `O(log n) + O(n)` for every query.

So for m queries in worst case it will be `mxO(logn + n)` which is too costly. I want this operations to be done efficiently less than `mxO(logn + n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an array you should use a balanced binary search tree. Insertion and lower/upper bounds (that is 'floor' and 'ceil') are all done in `O(log n)`, giving a total runtime of `O(m log m)`.

You didn't mention the language, but as an example, using the C++ `set` container (which implements a binary search tree) the code would look like this:

```
std::set<int> A;
A.insert(1);
A.insert(n);

for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    assert(1 < x && x < n);
    auto iter = A.insert(x).first;
    printf("floor: %d, ceil: %d\n", *prev(iter), *next(iter));
}
```